# Docker ENTRYPOINT/CMD cannot find file

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

This is so bewildering.

I have this simple Dockerfile, which uses npm install to install dependencies into node_modules:

```
FROM node:7

RUN chmod -R 777 $(npm root -g)
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm install github:sumanjs/suman#rebase_branch

COPY . .

RUN (cd node_modules && ls -a)  # 1 this logs expected stuff

RUN (cd node_modules/suman && ls -a)  # 2 this logs expected stuff

CMD ["node","/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js"]
```

it seems clear that the file is there after running

```
cd node_modules/suman && ls -a
```

but for some reason I get an error:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

If I use ENTRYPOINT instead like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js"]
```

(cli.js has a hashbang)

I get a similar error:

```
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js\": stat /usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js: no such file or directory"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js\": stat /usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js: no such file or directory".
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

This is very strange to me, I have used Docker for awhile now, and haven't seen anything like this before. Anyone know what might be up? It seems pretty clear that the file is missing, but I cannot figure out for the life of me why that would be. Especially considering when I use `ls -a`, the file appears to be present.

To prove it to you, this is the output of the second ls -a command:

```
Step 10/11 : RUN (cd node_modules/suman && ls -a)
 ---> Running in 0715d56e23a9
.
..
.babelrc
.npmignore
.tscmultiwatch
README.md
cli
cli.d.ts
cli.js       <<< dis my file
config
dist
dts
examples
lib
package.json
scripts
webpack.config.js
```

how bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Oh damn, so in the docker build step, the files were there, and `ls -a` revealed that.

But when I was running with docker run, I had this:

```
docker run -v "${project_root}/node_modules":/usr/src/app --name  ${container_name} ${image_tag}
```

so the node_modules dir in the container was being overwritten with the node_modules from outside the container which did not have the `suman` directory.

My bad fam.